# Diffusion current in semiconductor while applying an electric field

Tags: electric-fields, electric-current, semiconductor-physics

In case of intrinsic semiconductor, while applying an electric field, only drift current should exist, right? As diffusion current is due to concentration gradient. So the electron flow will be randomised. Ultimately, the current that will exist in the circuit will be due to applied electric field. I am a bit confused about this

Comment: What's the confusion?

Comment: There is always diffusion of charges in a semiconductor. Net diffusion current occurs when there is a concentration gradient. Even without one, electrons and holes are executing a random walk - it just doesn't create a net diffusion current.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't apply an E field the drift and diffusion current balance ( both flowing in opposite to each other). The diffusion current is quite small and does not depend on applied E. When E is applied the drift current changes and therefore the net flow of current across the diode is no longer zero. If the diode is reversed biased the diffusion current dominates. When it is forward biased the built in potential is lowered and the drift current is larger than the diffusion current.

Comment: Without applying an electric field, according to me the drift current would not exist as it caused due to electric field

Comment: There is the electric field from n to p due to the built in voltage difference. The few electrons on the p side done have any obstacle in going from p to n. This is the drift current.

Comment: OP asks about intrinsic sc so p vs n is not relevant

Answer (score 0):

You are right that the absence of a diffusion current implies no statistical trend in the carrier density from point to point. This however does not exclude the possibility of a non zero expectation for the carrier current<\i> density, which would arise from an applied field.